# Application implementation issues BEACON

Tags: android, beacon

I must develop an android application which will allow a customer who passes beacons can emmettre data on our web servers (web services).

I never develop under this technology.

I looked at the script with this: [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html)

But I do not see how to read a beacon to the client's path. The test application if I include allows to detect all beacons and display the information on this one.

Could you help and guide me?

Comment: Do you know how to make a web service call to your servers using Java on Android?  It seems this is the key thing that is needed to accomplish this, and not anything beacon specific.  I would look for a tutorial on this.

Comment: Hello, To do a HTTP request to server I know that. But not in android read a specific beacon and send it to my server.